# What is the PostFileWithRequest equivalent in ServiceStack's 'New API'?

Tags: servicestack

I want to post some request values alongside the multipart-formdata file contents. In the old API you could use PostFileWithRequest:

```
[Test]
public void Can_POST_upload_file_using_ServiceClient_with_request()
{
    IServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn);
    var uploadFile = new FileInfo("~/TestExistingDir/upload.html".MapProjectPath());
    var request = new FileUpload{CustomerId = 123, CustomerName = "Foo"};

    var response = client.PostFileWithRequest<FileUploadResponse>(ListeningOn + "/fileuploads", uploadFile, request);

    var expectedContents = new StreamReader(uploadFile.OpenRead()).ReadToEnd();

    Assert.That(response.FileName, Is.EqualTo(uploadFile.Name));
    Assert.That(response.ContentLength, Is.EqualTo(uploadFile.Length));
    Assert.That(response.Contents, Is.EqualTo(expectedContents));
    Assert.That(response.CustomerName, Is.EqualTo("Foo"));
    Assert.That(response.CustomerId, Is.EqualTo(123));
}
```

I can't find any such method in the new API, nor any overrides on client.Post() which suggest that this is still possible. Does anyone know if this is a feature that was dropped?

## Update

As @Mythz points out, the feature wasn't dropped. I had made the mistake of not casting the client:

```
private IRestClient CreateRestClient()
{
    return new JsonServiceClient(WebServiceHostUrl);
}

[Test]
public void Can_WebRequest_POST_upload_binary_file_to_save_new_file()
{
    var restClient = (JsonServiceClient)CreateRestClient(); // this cast was missing
    var fileToUpload = new FileInfo(@"D:/test/test.avi");
    var beforeHash = this.Hash(fileToUpload);

    var response = restClient.PostFileWithRequest<FilesResponse>("files/UploadedFiles/", fileToUpload, new TestRequest() { Echo = "Test"});

    var uploadedFile = new FileInfo(FilesRootDir + "UploadedFiles/test.avi");
    var afterHash = this.Hash(uploadedFile);

    Assert.That(beforeHas, Is.EqualTo(afterHash));
}

private string Hash(FileInfo file)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = file.OpenRead())
        {
            var bytes = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the old API was removed from the [C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client), only new API's were added.

The way you process an uploaded file inside a service also hasn't changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had a method that returned an IRestClient, and even though that internally was returning JsonServiceClient, the exposed client type was the base service client, which does not contain that PostFileWithRequest method. After casting the client correctly, the method was then available.